# Laravel : how to explode and showing multiple data in select2

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I am using select2 and i want to showing  multiple data from database in edit page

```
@foreach( $userLanguages as $userLanguageTitle)
 <option value="{{$user->languages}}">{{$userLanguageTitle}}</option>
@endforeach
```

But showing me

```
<select name="languages[]" class="select2 form-control" multiple="multiple" required>                                                                                                                   
<option value="English,Persian,German" >English</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="English,Persian,German" >Persian</option>                                                                                                               
<option value="English,Persian,German" >French</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="English,Persian,German" >German</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="English,Persian,German" >Spanish</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="English,Persian,German" >Turkish</option>                                                                                                   
<option value="English,Persian,German" >Italian</option>
</select>
```

I want show selected data in  element Like the example below

```
<select name="languages[]" class="select2 form-control" multiple="multiple" required>                                                                                                                   
<option value="English" selected >English</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="Persian" selected >Persian</option>                                                                                                               
<option value="French">French</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="German" selected >German</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="Spanish" >Spanish</option>                                                                                                                
<option value="Turkish" >Turkish</option>                                                                                                   
<option value="Italian" >Italian</option>
</select>
```

Model

```
public static function getUserlanguages()
{
    return [
        self::ENGLISH => 'English',
        self::PERSIAN => 'Persian',
        self::FRENCH => 'French',
        self::GERMAN => 'German',
        self::SPANISH => 'Spanish',
        self::TURKISH => 'Turkish',
        self::ITALIAN => 'Italian',
    ];
}
```

controller

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $userLanguages = User::getUserlanguages();
    return view('backend.users.edit', compact('user', 'userLanguages',));
}
```

Comment: can you show the controller and maybe dd($userLanguage)?

Comment: This does not make any sense, you are referring to the same variable and getting two different outputs. My hunch is there is something going with select2.

Comment: @Aless55 Edited Please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming `$user->languages` is a relation in `User` model and there is column `name` in `languages` table

```
@foreach($userLanguages as $userLanguageTitle)
 <option value="{{$userLanguageTitle}}" {{ (in_array($userLanguageTitle, $user->languages()->pluck('name')->toArray()) ? 'selected' : '') }}>{{$userLanguageTitle}}</option>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

`<option value="{{$user->languages}}">{{$userLanguageTitle}}</option>`

Since you edited the code above, I assume that `$user->languages` returns all **Languages** of an **User**. So it returns either a Collection or an Array but **not** a single Language item. So you can simply use `value="{{$userLanguageTitle}}"` to display the name of the language or you use the key of it like that:

```
@foreach( $userLanguages as $key => $userLanguageTitle)
 <option value="{{$key}}">{{$userLanguageTitle}}</option>
@endforeach
```